# Writing Byte Arrays to serial with Ruby

Tags: ruby, serial-port, arduino

I'm not clear on how to write simple byte code arrays with ruby, *more-so* I'm absolutely stumped on how to use the [Ruby SerialPort](http://github.com/toholio/ruby-serialport) library, well to be honest I have it working pretty well however I have only been successful in sending ASCII over the serial port.

For example it's really simple to write ASCII:

```
@sp = SerialPort.new "/dev/tty.usbserial-A6004cNN", 19200
@sp.write "test"
```

Which obviously writes `test` to that serial device. This works fine and I've been able to get all the expected results sent to a micro-controller ([arduino](http://www.arduino.cc/)) in this case. The issue is that I need to write output which the serial device will read like so:

```
{0x01,0x09,0x04,0x00, 'f',0xff,0xcc,0x33}
```

I've tried using [`str.unpack`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000760) but am still unable to produce the desired hex values output as bytes as above.

In Java it is simple using it's serial library:

```
byte[] cmd = { 0x01,0x09,0x04,0x00, 'f',(byte)0xff,(byte)0xcc,(byte)0x33 };
serialPort.write( cmd );
```

How can I output the proper bytecode to my serial device with Ruby?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
@sp.write [32.chr, 7.chr, 8.chr, 65.chr].to_s
@sp.write ["\x01\x09\x04\x00", 'f', "\xff\xcc\x33"].to_s
```

But we can have more fun than that (muhahaha...)

```
class Array
  def chr
    self.map { |e| e.chr }
  end
end
```

So then:

```
>> [1,2,3,65,66,67].chr
=> ["\001", "\002", "\003", "A", "B", "C"]
>> [1,2,3,65,66,67].chr.to_s
=> "\001\002\003ABC"
```

Comment: wow... great. I didn’t realize it could be that simple. Thanks!